# Start New Process after Exiting Perl Script

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

I'm fairly new to Perl so please bear with me.  I would like to initiate a c# program at exit of a Perl script.  Is this possible?  If I just make a call (say to some arbitrary other Perl script) the parent process will not exit until the child process dies.  Is there any way to break this relationship in Perl?  I considered just writing to a file but this would require that I always run a monitoring service in the background which is not ideal.

I've tried system() but was unsuccessful.  Here is a snippet from my code:

Primary Script:

```
...
print "primary call starting\n";
system('reboot.pl');
$count++;
sleep(1);
print "primary call ending\n";
...
```

Secondary Script (reboot.pl):

```
...
print "reboot starting\n";
system('timeout 10');
my $iboot_urlcall = $ua->request($iboot_off);
system('timeout 10');
my $iboot_urlcall = $ua->request($iboot_on);
system('timeout 10');
print "reboot ending\n";
...
```

The stdout result of running this is:

```
primary call starting
reboot starting

timeout

timeout

timeout
reboot ending
primary call ending
...
```

My desired output would be more like....

```
primary call starting
reboot starting
primary call ending
timeout

timeout

timeout
reboot ending
...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How are you initiating the Perl script?

Comment: A piece of hardware is making a url call to the cgi script.  I would normally initiate the additional script going this route as well however I cannot change the firmware on the hardware (I can, it's just a restriction).

Comment: On Linux/Unix systems you can use the `exec` built-in which replaces the current program (in this case the `perl` interpreter) by the given one. `perldoc -f exec`

Comment: I believe the current program is still being blocked however.  I could be wrong..

Comment: My hardware is really just waiting for an "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" message when the CGI script exits.  Is there a good way for me to fake this message before exit?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Unix:

```
system ( 'your_command &' );
```

will return immediately, and leave your process running in the background.

Comment: Right, this is one thing that I tried but then realized that the hardware is waiting for an OK response from the first perl script.  I could have my secondary script make a call to the primary one and that would allow primary to exit before secondary however I can't make a call to the secondary script from the hardware which makes that direction moot.  Otherwise the system() call will be a blocking event (the secondary script is basically a command then a 30 second delay then another command with a delay).

Comment: I'm not following you. I've just tested doing this with a very basic `system ( 'sleep 136 &' );` - this existed immediately, but the 'sleep' process was spawned as expected. If you're doing a composite command, you may need to bracket it. E.g. `system('(sleep 32;echo sleep done) &');`

Comment: I added some more to my post to elaborate a little more clearly.  It is possible that I'm using system incorrectly.

Comment: I'm even less clear about what you're trying to accomplish now - where does c# come into it? `timeout 10` is a windows call, presumably we're talking Windows perl here? Anyway - your 'caller' script can either: Start your `reboot.pl` and return, or track `reboot.pl` as it's running. You're trying to do a halfway option, and you don't really have the right tools to do that. I'd offer the alternative - merge the two scripts, and use a thread to run the 'reboot' part.